# ios - keeping a thread alive for NSURLConnection delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I would like to pass a block to an NSOperationQueue to operate on a background thread.

In the block I wish to use NSURLConnection to download a very large file - using asynchronous because I want to save as I go along to ensure that I don't have to reload whole file if the network drops / app closes etc..

I would like to know how to keep the thread alive to service the delegate callbacks. Do I need to set up a NSRunLoop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set up a long-living worker thread like AsiHttpRequest and AFNetworking network library do, the answer is YES.

Sample Code of the worker thread from AFNetworking:

```
+ (void)networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:(id)__unused object {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"AFNetworking"];

        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runLoop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [runLoop run];
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, this is exactly want I want - I guess I should of had a look through either of those libraries to see how they did it. Thanks

Comment: Check out AsiHttpRequest and AFNetworking. They do it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection delegate is already working in the background asynchronous

You can Use this method from the main thread

```
+ (NSURLConnection *)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate
```

Or If you want to run it on an OperationQueue just use

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

Answer (score 0):

For downloading large files you are better off utilizing `NSURLSession` and a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`. See here the official docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadTask_class/Reference/Reference.html

If you want to use `NSURLConnection` anyway, I would suggest to implement the delegates (NSURLConnectionDataDelegate and NSURLConnectionDelegate). In the `connection:didReceiveData:` delegate write (append) each data chunk to a file.

Strictly, you don't need a background thread where the delegate methods will be executed. Saving to a file is quite fast.

You can take a look here in this snippet which implements a basic NSURLConnection employing the the delegate approach, running on the main thread: https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/5764723

Implementing a *resumable* download is actually more elaborate, and requires to be familiar with the HTTP protocol.